# How to retrieve Facebook Messenger Code (the unique image id) programmatically

Tags: facebook-messenger

I am building an app that uses [Facebook Messenger Platform](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform), and want to make use of the Messenger Codes that look like this:

[image: Messenger Code for CNN]

Currently, I am able to retrieve it from the chat interface manually, which is hidden at the bottom (the circular pattern), shown here:

[image: button for retrieving messenger code]

However, I would like to get this programmatically, and there is nothing that I can find in the docs that suggest that this is possible. When retrieving the image, we can inspect the URL as such:

```
https://business.facebook.com/messenger_code/generate/?image_format=image%2Fpng&image_size=420&profile_id=profile_id_goes_here&ext=ext_not_sure_what_this_is&hash=a_hash
```

Note that I've removed any ids and what not from the above, but without any of these, the image will not generate. Notably, I need ext and hash to get it to work, both of which changes from page to page.

I am assuming that hash is some sort of hash of the a name or profile image or something, while ext is something else altogether. Is anyone familiar with how I could generate the URL?

Answer (score 0):

The new messenger code API allows you to retrieve the code programmatically

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/messenger-code

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "type": "standard",
  "image_size": 1000
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_codes?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```